# Rotations after inserting element in AVL-tree

Tags: computer-science, trees

We want to insert $58$ at the following AVL-tree and then we have to make rotations so that the tree is balanced. According to my notes, we are at the case RL (The first edge leads to the right and the second to the left), where two rotations are required, one right around the next of the critical node and a left one, around the critical node.

[image]

But why are we at the case RL, although the first edge from the critical point to the new-inserted element is a left one and the second a right one?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the diagrams on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) which show you how the heights of the subtrees involved change, which will then tell you why you need to use the rotations for the RL case. If you use only one rotation, that middle subtree will stay at the same height and it will remain unbalanced. Don't simply memorize which case it is supposed to be based on some obscure rules like the one you mention. It is easy if you understand what the rotations really do. Also, you don't have to do rotations, but can simply take the subtrees and nodes and rearrange them so that their order is preserved. That way is in fact more intuitive than trying to imagine rotations of some sort.

Comment: I see..Thank you!!! If we had this AVL-tree: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hjyC4.png and would like to delete the node with the number 19, would we replece 19 with 52 since it is the next in the in-order traversal and then we would become this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/9BqNb.png and since it is balanced we don't have to make further rotations? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @evinda: Yup it's balanced. By the way besides AVL trees you should also try using the AVL balancing technique on a binary tree with only the leaves containing the list of elements in order. That way takes up more space but makes everything much cleaner, and in fact is easily adapted to make it into things like a min-heap or a range query data structure.

Comment: So is that what I did  right? Could you give me an example of such a tree? :/

Comment: Then I deleted 4 and I got this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOYzn.png and  then I deleted 56 and got this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9Ex.png

$$$$
Could you tell me if it is right? Because in my lecture notes, there are different results.

Comment: @evinda: When you delete 4 your result isn't right because each node by definition must have either 0 or 2 children. There are complicated rules which are all unnecessary if you put all the data at the leaves. Just try it. I don't know where to get nice diagrams for that but it is really trivial. Just insert/delete in the obvious way and rebalance every node on the path back to the root if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't all the nodes have to have at most 2 children, but it is allowed that a node has one child? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @evinda: The version I know does not allow one child.